# Sequelize nested associations with 3 tables

Tags: node.js, nested, associations, sequelize.js

I have a little problem with associations on query, I've nested assocations (4 tables, `Users`, `A`, `B` & `C`, `Users` **hasOne** `A`, `A` **hasMany** `B` and **belongsTo** `Users`, `B` **belongsTo** `A` and **hasMany** `C` and `C` **belongsTo** `B`).

When I do a findOne on `Users`, including my 3 other tables like that :

```
Models.User.findOne({
  where: { id: req.user.id },
  include:[{
    model: Models.Candidate, // Candidate Associations (user.candidate) (Table A)
    as: 'candidate',
    include:[{
      model: Models.Experience, // (Table B) Experiences Associations (user.candidate.experiences)
      as: 'experiences',
      include: [{
        model: Models.Service,
        as: 'service'
      }
      }] // Service Associations (Table C)
    }]
  }]
})
```

I correctly get the searched row but the problem is on the left outer join query of the third assocations (table `C`), the generated query is

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Services` AS `candidate->experiences->service` ON `candidate->experiences`.`id` = `candidate->experiences->service`.`id`
```

But I want to have this query :

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Services` AS `candidate->experiences->service` ON `candidate->experiences`.`service_id` = `candidate->experiences->service`.`id`
```

So how can I do that ?

I searched some help on google and other forum and websites but I didn't manage to find my answer since few weeks.

Thanks a lot for help that you'll provide me !

**Edit :**

Here is my models :

**User :**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['admin', 'candidate', 'es', 'demo'],
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasOne(models.Candidate, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'candidate'
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

**Candidate (A) :**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Candidate = sequelize.define('Candidate', {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    es_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    photo: DataTypes.STRING,
    video: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: DataTypes.STRING,
    note: DataTypes.STRING,
    views: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Candidate.associate = (models) => {
    Candidate.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
    Candidate.hasMany(models.Experience, {
      foreignKey: 'candidate_id',
      as: 'experiences'
    });
  };
  return Candidate;
};
```

**Experience (B) :**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Experience = sequelize.define('Experience', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    candidate_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    poste_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    service_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    internship: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    start: DataTypes.DATE,
    end: DataTypes.DATE,
    current: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {});
  Experience.associate = function (models) {
    Experience.belongsTo(models.Candidate, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
    Experience.hasOne(models.Service, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      targetKey: 'service_id',
      as: 'service'
    });
  };
  return Experience;
};
```

**Service (C) :**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Service = sequelize.define('Service', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {});
  Service.associate = function (models) {
    Service.belongsTo(models.Experience, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return Service;
};
```

Comment: You could add the code of your models please

Comment: Models added in the topic

Comment: Any help here please ?

Comment: @Сорокдва Do you found any solution?